# Firefox, Unwanted "window in window" upon first instance of firefox starting

Tags: firefox, gui, browser

When opening a single instance of Firefox, I get a "window within a window" (see screenshot below). Both sets of minimize/maximize/close buttons perform the same for the double windowed browser. Both browsers are fully functional otherwise.

- If I drag a tab out of this and create a window, the problem goes away.
- If I launch Firefox after restarting the system, the problem still persists.
- If I launch a second instance of Firefox with original window still open, problem does NOT persist on 2nd window.
- Manually closing ALL tabs (vs. just closing the window) and
  reopen Firefox, this behavior continues to exist (and I can still
  recover tabs with ctrl+shift+t)

My best guess is this may have something to do with automatic tab recovery/ the first instance of Firefox starting on the device at a given time, but I have no idea why this behavior exists. Thanks for any ideas!

[Window in Window Firefox issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuwNL.png)

[Desired Firefox window behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEzxw.png)

```
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

(MATE)

Firefox for Ubuntu ver. 92.0
```

Comment: Problem with the Mate window manager or compositor? Check "More tools" - "Customize toolbar...": does the problem persist if you check "titlebar" on the last line (or turn it off)?